# How to print information about products in my cart with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

In my Database "**shoppinp-cart-system**" i have 4 tables: 
"**cart**", "**cart_product**", "**users**" and "**products**" I want to get the current user cart and print the products, but not only the product name, but the full characteristics i.e Name, Price, Image and Quantity.

Here is my function listCartAction() in my CartController:

```
/**
 * @Route("/cart/show/{id}", name="cart_list")
 */
public function listCartAction($id)
{
    $cart = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:CartProduct')->find($id);

    $cartProducts = $cart->getProduct();

    return $this->render('cart/cart.view.html.twig', array(
        'cart' => $cartProducts
    ));
}
```

And the Twig Template:

```
`{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <h1>Products In My Cart</h1>
        </div>
        {% for c in cart %}
            <h1>{{ c.product }}</h1>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}`
```

Cart Entity:`

```
<?

php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Cart
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="cart")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CartRepository")
 */
class Cart
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_updated", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateUpdated;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set userId
     *
     * @param integer $userId
     *
     * @return Cart
     */
    public function setUserId($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreated
     *
     * @return Cart
     */
    public function setDateCreated($dateCreated)
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateUpdated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateUpdated
     *
     * @return Cart
     */
    public function setDateUpdated($dateUpdated)
    {
        $this->dateUpdated = $dateUpdated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateUpdated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateUpdated()
    {
        return $this->dateUpdated;
    }
}
```

`
Cart Product Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * CartProduct
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="cart_product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CartProductRepository")
 */
class CartProduct
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Cart
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Cart")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cart_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $cart;

    /**
     * @var \stdClass
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer")
     */
    private $quantity;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set cart
     *
     * @param \stdClass $cart
     *
     * @return CartProduct
     */
    public function setCart($cart)
    {
        $this->cart = $cart;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cart
     *
     * @return Cart
     */
    public function getCart()
    {
        return $this->cart;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @var Product
     *
     * @return CartProduct
     */
    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     * @var Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     *
     * @return CartProduct
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that your entities and mappings are correct you need to return the `Cart` entity instead of `CartProduct`. Remember that you can use symfony's parameter converter, something like this:

```
/**
* @Route("/cart/show/{id}", name="cart_list")
*/
public function listCartAction(Cart $cart) //Remember to import the Cart class!
{
    return $this->render('cart/cart.view.html.twig', array(
        'cart' => $cart
    ));
}
```

Twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <h1>Products In My Cart</h1>
        </div>
        {% for p in cart.products %}
            <h1>{{ p.name }}</h1>
            <p>{{ p.price }}</p>
            //Render other products properties here...
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Symfony paramconverter docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

**EDIT - After you posted your entities**

```
/**
* @Route("/cart/show/{id}", name="cart_list")
*/
public function listCartAction($id)
{
    $cartProducts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:CartProduct')
        ->findByCart($id);

    return $this->render('cart/cart.view.html.twig', array(
        'cartProducts' => $cartProducts
    ));
}
```

Twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <h1>Products In My Cart</h1>
        </div>
        {% for cp in cartProducts %}
            <h1>{{ cp.product.name }}</h1>
            <p>{{ cp.product.price }}</p>
            <p>{{ cp.quantity }}</p>
            //Render other products properties here...
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have getProducts() function in My CartProduct, so instead Cart $cart i used CartProduct $cart. Anyway, when i try to use p.name in twig it throws me this: 

AppBundle\Entity\CartProduct object not found.

Comment: So your entities and mappings are probably wrong. You should have a `getProducts()` in your `Cart` entity, not in `CartProduct`.

Comment: I edit my question, now you can see my 2 entities, i think they're not wrong

Comment: @RumenPanchev I've edited my answer after checking your entities code.

Comment: The output is empty, there is nothing to show. I can't undarstand what is this method find ->findByCart($id) ? @Renan Taranto

Comment: @RumenPanchev It should output if you have any persisted `CartProduct` related to a `Cart` and a `Product`. This method will get all `CartProduct` entities related to the given `Cart` id.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, thats the reason why i'm asking bro. Please stop explain me why, i need examples. I want to learn Symfony with practice, not advices.